# Daily CPU and memory statistics on Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, cpu-usage, memory-usage

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine which gets very high CPU and memory load in certain periods of the day. I need an application that creates a 24h log with the CPU and memory usage. 
I tried to configure PerfMon to 24 hours use but it has a limit of 1000 seconds.

Is there any free lightweight application that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using PerfMon live, use a data collection set to save performance counter data to a file. This file can then be opened in PerfMon for viewing later (including selecting subsets of the collection counters and over shorter time intervals). PowerShell also has some cmdlets that will [process the files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/02/use-powershell-to-parse-saved-performance-counter-logs.aspx).

If you select CSV as the file format, then the files can be opened in Excel and other tools for processing.

Answer (score 2):

1000 seconds? where do you get that from? Just use or create a new data collection set in perfmon, they can run for years and are ideal for this kind of thing.